# matplotlib increase xticks but labels stay the same number

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 559 rows and 1 column (+1 which is the timestamp) in the form of

```
_time                                                   Temperatura
(2023-06-22 14:10:38+00:00, 2023-06-22 14:10:38+00:00)  39.00
(2023-06-22 14:10:40+00:00, 2023-06-22 14:10:40+00:00)  39.30
```

I have correctly plotted and increased the xticks with

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(15, 10))
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Gradi °C")
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=12)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(True)
loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=50) # this locator puts ticks at regular intervals
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.show()
```

The issue I'm seeing is that, even if the xticks increase, the labels on the xticks doesn't increase.

`print(df.dtypes)` shows

```
Temperatura    float64
dtype: object
```

[image]

How can I have the same amount of labels as the xticks?

Comment: What is the dtype for the x-axis?

Comment: @fdireito how do I know?

Comment: What does ```df.dtypes``` report?

Comment: @fdireito object (see updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I may have found the solution

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax = df.plot(title='Temperatura', ylabel='Gradi [°C]', xlabel='Tempo',x_compat=True,grid=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.show()
```

`mdates.MinuteLocator()` set the xtick on every minute meanwhile `mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')` show the label in the format hours:minute

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to manually set xticks?

> Axes.set_xticks(ticks, labels=None, *, minor=False, **kwargs)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

x_labels = ... 
xs = np.arange(len(x_labels))
ax.set_xticks(xs, x_labels)
```

Comment: no, labels must be taken automatically from the _time column in my dataframe